# how i can change background color of full page using onclick event in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I need to solve a question that is asking to change the body background colours while clicking the button I need to change four colours how I can solve it? in react.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
 var colors=[
{
  value:1,label:"red"
},
{
  value:2,label:"green"
}
]
 var [setbgcolor,ddlvalue]=useState(colors.label)
var ddlhandle=e=>{
ddlvalue(e.label)
}
return (
<div className="App">
<style>{'body {background-color:'+setbgcolor+'}'}</style>
<button onClick={ddlhandle} >click</button>
<select options={colors} onChange={ddlhandle}></select>
</div>
);
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Please share the code you tried so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need two states, one for holding the `select`'s value, and other for holding current bg color.  Similarly, you need two handlers, one for `select` and other for `button`. Also, you need to use `option` element, inside `select` to display the options.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  var colors = [
    {
      value: 1,
      label: "red"
    },
    {
      value: 2,
      label: "green"
    }
  ];
  var [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(colors[0].label);
  var [bgcolor, setbgColor] = useState(colors[0].label);
  var ddlhandle = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };

  var buttonHandle = () => {
    setbgColor(inputValue);
  };
  return (
    <div
      style={{ backgroundColor: bgcolor, width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}
      className="App"
    >
      <button onClick={buttonHandle}>click</button>
      <select onChange={ddlhandle}>
        {colors.map((color) => (
          <option value={color.label}>{color.label}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-williamson-58qf8?file=/src/App.js

---

Edit: Since you need to change the color of entire `body`, you need to set `width: "100vw"` and `height: "100vh"` of `div`.

Answer (score 1):

you should use two className or two style for the background

and handle a parameter for change between className or style

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
 var colors=[
{
  value:1,label:"red"
},
{
  value:2,label:"green"
}
]
 var [setbgcolor,ddlvalue]=useState(colors[0].label)
var ddlhandle=e=>{

ddlvalue(e.target.value)
}
return (
**<div className="App" style={{backgroundColor:`${setbgcolor}`}}>**
<button onClick={ddlhandle} >click</button>
<select options={colors} onChange={ddlhandle}></select>
</div>
);
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Not getting results what to do? I need to submit assignment

Answer (score 0):

If you want with a single click of a button to cicle thru an array of possible colors to change the background color, you can simply store the array index of the current one and `+1` to it until you reach the limit then reset back to `0`.

Heres a short example:

Created an array with objects that represent what colors can be picked

```
const colors = [
    { title: "Red", color: "#de1212" },
    { title: "Blue", color: "#122dde" },
    { title: "Green", color: "#32a852" },
    { title: "Yellow", color: "#d7de12" }
];
```

Then created a state where you can store the index of the current selected color. NOTE giving a default index of 0

```
const [colorValue, setColorValue] = useState(0);
```

Then simply, create a simple method that `onClick` will execute. This method will increate the index by 1 until it reaches same number as there are objects in the array. Once reached the limit it will reset it to 0

```
  const handleClick = () =>
    setColorValue(colorValue + 1 < colors.length ? colorValue + 1 : 0);
```

Now in a render its up to you how you render it. I simply did this to present it

```
<div className="App" style={{ backgroundColor: colors[colorValue].color }}>
      <h1>Selected color: {colors[colorValue].title}</h1>
      <button className="btn" onClick={handleClick}>
        Click to change color
      </button>
</div>
```

[Live example of this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-hill-2hd48?file=/src/App.js:444-691)

And if you required to do this with a `select` and only with a button `onClick` to read `select` value and set it as color, the situation is the same just add 1 more state where you seperatly store `select` value OR use a `ref`. The rest is the same.

Also, as a note, do not use `var`. Its so old. Use `let`, for variables that values change, and `const`, for variables whos value do not change.